# Debugging Help - set a value in debug mode?

Tags: c#, debugging

I am debugging and I hit my break point. I hover over a variable and I get the standard drilldown. I see a Nullable prop and it is null. I right click and choose "edit value". No matter what I seem to type, I get "The value could not be set. Please check your entry." 
I have tried 5/1/09, new DateTime(2009, 5, 1), {05/01/2009}... pretty much every flavor I could think of. What the heck am I doing wrong? I would like to code in the value and continue debugging with the new value.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, ~ck

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  This seems to work fine for me with VS 2008.  A code sample might also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime.Parse("5/1/2009")

Answer (score 2):

Seems easy to me. I had this line:

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000");
```

Hit the breakpoint, and typed this into the immediate window:

```
dt = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2010")
```

The same technique also works when editing the value in the debugger tooltip, the locals window, the autos window, the watch window and even the quick watch window.

Answer (score 0):

Try using #5/1/2009#

Answer (score 0):

In a Watch window line, type this in the name field:

```
dt = new DateTime(2009,5,1)
```

The line will be disabled so just delete it.  In the next line, type in *dt* and it will be the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this object a "DateTime" or a "Nullable" (which is the same as "DateTime?")?